# conforming to Sequence and IteratorProtocol in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, sequence, swift-protocols

I am trying to write my own version of `IndexingIterator` to increase my understanding of `Sequence`. I haven't assign any type to associatetype Iterator in my struct. However, the complier doesn't complain about that and I get a default implementation of `makeIterator`.

Following are my codes:

```
struct __IndexingIterator<Elements: IndexableBase>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() -> Elements._Element? {
        return nil
    }
}
let iterator = __IndexingIterator<[String]>()
// this works and returns an instance of __IndexingIterator<Array<String>>. why?
iterator.makeIterator()
```

I think there must be some extensions on `Sequence` which add the default implementation. Thus, I searched it in `Sequence.swift` and only found this.

```
extension Sequence where Self.Iterator == Self, Self : IteratorProtocol {
  /// Returns an iterator over the elements of this sequence.
  public func makeIterator() -> Self {
    return self
  }
}
```

I thought it would be like this:

```
extension Sequence where Self: IteratorProtocol {
    typealias Iterator = Self
    ...
}
```

Did I miss something or I misunderstood the extension?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Alexander's answer is correct. Here's a boiled down version, without using `Sequence`:

```
protocol MySequence {
    associatedtype Iterator: IteratorProtocol
    func maakeIterator() -> Iterator
}

extension MySequence where Self.Iterator == Self, Self : IteratorProtocol {
    /// Returns an iterator over the elements of this sequence.
    func maakeIterator() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}

struct __IndexingIterator<Element>: MySequence, IteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        return nil
    }
}

let iterator = __IndexingIterator<[String]>()
iterator.maakeIterator()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Iterator which confrom to `IteratorProtocol` first, then write what you need confrom to `Sequence`.

Make sure that you have to implement requried func.

```
   struct IteratorTest : IteratorProtocol {
        typealias Element = Int

        var count : Int

        init(count :Int) {
            self.count = count
        }

        mutating func next() -> Int? {
            if count == 0 {
                return nil
            }else {
                defer {
                    count -= 1
                }
                return count;
            }
        }
    }

    struct CountDown : Sequence {
        typealias Iterator = IteratorTest
        func makeIterator() -> IteratorTest {
            return IteratorTest.init(count: 10)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type alias isn't necessary, because the `Element` associated type is  inferred from your implementation of `next()`.

Here's a simple example:

```
protocol ResourceProvider {
    associatedtype Resoruce
    func provide() -> Resoruce;
}

struct StringProvider {
    func provide() -> String { // "Resource" inferred to be "String"
        return "A string"
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you on your example, but I don't think it can explain my issue. I think the associatedtype `Element` in IteratorProtocol can be inferred to be `_IndexableBase._Element`, but the associatedtype `Iterator` in `Sequence` can't be inferred because my definition of `__IndexingIterator` lacks type assignment for `Iterator`. And I need an explanation for that.

Comment: That extension you showed (the second last code snippet) defines a default implementation for types that are both sequences and integrators. This extension makes it so by default, such types conform to `Sequence` by return themselves for `makeIterator()`. `__IndexingIterator` fits the criteria, because it both a sequence and an iterator. As a result it gains this default implementation of `makeIterator`. This default implementation returns a `Self` type, which resolves to `__IndexingIterator` in this context.

Comment: The compiler also knows that the return type of `makeIterator` is the associated type `Iterator`, so it puts 2 and 2 together to conclude that `Iterator` is `__IndexingIterator`

Comment: Interestingggg that's a very good point. I'll need to think about this

Comment: you said "__IndexingIterator fits the criteria, because it both a sequence and an iterator", but I doubt about that. The extension has a precondition `Self.Iterator == Self`, and that is where my confusion lies. Could you please explain how `__IndexingIterator` is proved to be `Self.Iterator == Self`?